# PHP Alternative to if (!isset(...)) {...} => GetVar($Variable, $ValueIfNotExists)

Tags: php, variables, exists, isset

When I use a **variable** in PHP which **does not exist**, I will get a warning/error message.

> Notice:  Undefined variable

So usually I'm writing an if-statement to initialize it first.

Example 1:

```
if (!isset($MySpecialVariable))
{
  $MySpecialVariable = 0;
}
$MySpecialVariable++;
```

Example 2:

```
if (!isset($MyArray["MySpecialIndex"]))
{
  $MyArray["MySpecialIndex"] = "InitialValue";
}
$Value = $MyArray["MySpecialIndex"];
```

The disadvantage is that I have to write `$MySpecialVariable` or `$MyArray["MySpecialIndex"]` several times and the program gets bloated.

How can I achieve the same result with writing the variable only **once**?

I'm looking for something like

```
GetVar($MySpecialVariable, 0); # Sets MySpecialVariable to 0 only if not isset()
$MySpecialVariable++;

$Value = GetVar($MyArray["MySpecialIndex"], "InitialValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are running PHP7 you can use the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)
Like:

```
$myVar = $myVar ?? 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function GetVar(&$MyVar, $ValueIfVarIsNotSet)
{
    $MyVar = (isset($MyVar)) ? $MyVar : $ValueIfVarIsNotSet;
    return $MyVar;
}
```

The key is to to pass the requested variable by reference (`&$MyVar`). Otherwise it is not possible to call a function with a possibly uninitialized variable.

**Test code:**

```
echo "<pre>";

unset($a);
$b = "ValueForB";
unset($c);
$d = "ValueForD";

echo (isset($a)) ? "a exists" : "a NotSet";
$a = GetVar($a, 7); # $a can be passed even if it is not set here
$a++;
echo "\nValue=$a\n";
echo (isset($a)) ? "a exists" : "a NotSet";
echo "\n\n";

echo (isset($b)) ? "b exists" : "b NotSet";
echo "\nValue=".GetVar($b, "StandardValue2")."\n";
echo (isset($b)) ? "b exists" : "b NotSet";
echo "\n\n";

echo (isset($c)) ? "c exists" : "c NotSet";
echo "\nValue=".GetVar($c, "StandardValue3")."\n";
echo (isset($a)) ? "c exists" : "c NotSet";
echo "\n\n";

echo (isset($d)) ? "d exists" : "d NotSet";
echo "\nValue=".GetVar($d, "StandardValue4")."\n";
echo (isset($d)) ? "d exists" : "d NotSet";
echo "\n\n";

echo "</pre>";
```

**Output:**

> a NotSet
>   Value=8
>   a exists
>   
>   b exists
>   Value=ValueForB
>   b exists
>   
>   c NotSet
>   Value=StandardValue3
>   c exists
>   
>   d exists
>   Value=ValueForD
>   d exists